# HTML5 file upload, without saving to disk

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

Is it possible to perform a file upload using HTML5 and jQuery, without saving the file to disk server side?

Basically, I want to upload a file and process it immediately. I don't want to save it to disk, since there is no need to. It'll add a lot of potentially unnecessary code.

If so, does anyone have an example? I couldn't seem to find an example on Google, so I"m wondering if this is possible or not.

EDIT: I want to upload to the server and process there, without saving. I'm using PHP, with CakePHP

Comment: Do you want to process it on the client, or upload to the server and process there (without saving ofc).  If server-side, what server-side tech are you using?

Comment: I want to upload to the server and process there, without saving. I'm using PHP, with CakePHP

Comment: You should include that information in your question and tags (update the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think it is possible, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269564/simple-client-side-file-processing-without-refresh) answered by [JayC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498856/jayc)

> What you're talking about is the HTML5 File API. I'm not sure what is
>   the best link to describe it, but this might help.
>   [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications](http://What%20you're%20talking%20about%20is%20the%20HTML5%20File%20API.%20I'm%20not%20sure%20what%20is%20the%20best%20link%20to%20describe%20it,%20but%20this%20might%20help.%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281775/get-data-from-file-input-in-jquery) maybe can help you as well

Comment: Clarification made by the questioner:  it's server-side processing rather than client-side.

Comment: well this answer is still going to achieve the same result whether its server side processing or client side. In the linked answered question, the example creates a base64 string of the file, that could then be sent to the server, for processing. The reason I have accepted this answer already is I was wondering if someone else has a better answer, than converting to base64. As I imagine converting to base64 will add additional overhead. Might as well just do a normal file upload then.